# Google Maps Marker Clustering

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, markerclusterer

I've added updated [`Google-Maps-iOS-Utils` library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering) manually in my project for marker clustering. In cluster manager array, a cluster item is an object of the `Spot` class having property marker. No error is showing, but custom marker and cluster both are showing. On tapping on cluster item it displays default map marker as well.

My code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/37).
Any ideas for how I can solve this?

Comment: What is the issue? The cluster and the markers are showing at the same time?

Comment: yes.i want to replace the default marker icon with my custom marker icon

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your marker icon inside cluster like this:

Add `GMUClusterRendererDelegate` and it's function:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
        if marker.userData is Spot{
            marker.icon = UIImage(named: "YourMarkerImageName")
        }
    }
```

If you want to change the cluster icon:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
            if marker.userData is Spot{
                marker.icon = UIImage(named: "YourMarkerImageName")
            }else{
                marker.icon = UIImage(named: "YourClusterImageName")
            }
        }
```